# how to bypass Allow-Access-Control-Origin?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web

if someone had a web-service but did not set header Allow-Access-Control-Origin:*

Then how exactly do I make the request and get the resource?

http://www.random.org/clients/http/ states a web service that can be called as follows: http://www.random.org/integers/?num=10&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new

When I tried to access it through XHR I had **Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**.

I know this is normal, I just want to know how exactly did the creators of the API expect me to call it if they did not set those headers appropriately?

Or is there anyway around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the request from a machine you control (i.e. your server) and not one that you don't (i.e. your visitor's browser)

Comment: Isn't the whole point of web services to be callable through the visitor's browser? My question is how did http://www.random.org/clients/http/ expect us to call its web service if he did not set the appropriate headers for us to do so?

Comment: No. The whole point of web services is to be accessible via HTTP.

Comment: Ok yes but i can't access it through XHR?

Comment: Not directly. You can make a request to your own server and have it proxy the data.